# How do I clean data that was read by Azure's Ai form Recognizer?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pdf

```
def process_invoice(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
            content_type = 'application/pdf'  # replace with the correct content type for your files
            poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_content(f, content_type=content_type)
            result = [page.to_dict() for page in poller.result()]

            # Save JSON output to a file
            cleaned_result = clean_json(result)
            json_file_path = os.path.join(json_folder_path, f'{os.path.basename(file_path)}.json')
            with open(json_file_path, 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(cleaned_result, json_file)

            # Load JSON file into a pandas DataFrame
            try:
                df = pd.json_normalize(cleaned_result, record_path=['tables', 'cells'], errors='ignore')
            except KeyError as e:
                print(f"An error occurred while normalizing the data: {str(e)}")
                print("Adjusting parameters for pd.json_normalize()...")
                df = pd.json_normalize(cleaned_result)  # adjust parameters as needed based on your JSON structure

            # Convert DataFrame to CSV and save to the same folder
            csv_file_path = os.path.join(csv_folder_path, f'{os.path.basename(file_path)}.csv')
            df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False)

    except Exception as ErrorCode:
        print(f'An error occurred while processing the file {file_path}: {str(ErrorCode)}')
        exit(1)

def clean_json(data):
    # Iterate over each page in the data
    for page in data:
        if 'tables' in page:
            # Iterate over each table in the 'tables' list of the page
            for table in page['tables']:
                # Iterate over each cell in the 'cells' list of the table
                for cell in table['cells']:
                    # If the cell is a dictionary and contains any of the fields 'x', 'y', or 'confidence', delete them
                    for field in ['x', 'y', 'confidence']:
                        if field in cell:
                            del cell[field]
    return data
```

This takes in the path of a Json that was read from a PDF through Azure's Ai form recognizer, Azure's form recognizer which returns bounding boxes in the form of an x, & y float, it also returns a confidence value which is unneeded data. I made a clean_json method to clean out the data but the data itself was still included. Is there any examples of json cleaner methods that allow for the removal of nested data values within the json format? This data is also being inserted into an Excel sheet, that's why I'm transferring this data into a CSV as excels tend to have an easier time with CSV's vs Json.

```
{"text": "Price", "bounding_box": [{"x": 6.4862, "y": 2.9103}, {"x": 6.8347, "y": 2.9103}, {"x": 6.8347, "y": 3.0255}, {"x": 6.4862, "y": 3.0255}], "confidence": 1.0, "page_number": 1, "kind": "word"}]}, {"text": "Amount", "row_index": 0, "column_index": 4, "row_span": 1, "column_span": 1, "is_header": true, "is_footer": false, "page_number": 1, "bounding_box": [{"x": 7.091, "y": 2.8584}, {"x": 7.9094, "y": 2.8584}, {"x": 7.9094, "y": 3.0888}, {"x": 7.091, "y": 3.0888}]
```

This is a snippet of the data returned by Azure in the form of a Json, the only data necessary to be converted into a CSV is the text : "Data" and the is_header and is_footer values but the data is wrapped in a field elements header and is nested within the text column.

I tried to implement a cleaner method in python using pandas but the end result had no affect on the overall data.